# Xubuntu transparent buttons in the panel

Tags: xfce, customization, xfce-panel

I would like to remove the color behind the buttons inside the XFCE Panel.

I tried to modify the file `/usr/share/themes/Greybird/gtk-2.0/apps/xfce-panel.rc`, and I came with a strange white behind the buttons. I would like to make it transparent.

I think I only have to work with this part of the code :

```
   style "window-buttons" = "theme-panel"
   {
        xthickness      = 3
        ythickness      = 3

        bg[ACTIVE]      = @bg_color_dark
        bg[PRELIGHT]    = @bg_color_dark
        bg[SELECTED]    = @bg_color_dark

        fg[NORMAL]      = @bg_color_dark
        fg[ACTIVE]      = @bg_color_dark
        fg[PRELIGHT]    = @bg_color_dark

        engine "murrine" {
                contrast = 0.0
                gradient_shades = { 1.0, 0.9, 0.8, 0.7 }
                roundness       = 0.5
                reliefstyle     = 0
                textstyle       = 1
                text_shade      = 0.2
        }
    }
```

What should I modify ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No file editing is necessary.

First, Make sure the compositor is enabled in the settings (**Main Menu >> Settings >> Window Manager Tweaks >> Compositor**).

Then, right-click on the panel, open the panel's preferences, open the tab **Appearance**, set the Opacity to 0.

Finally, open the **Window Buttons** plugin settings, and uncheck **Show flat buttons**.

For more information, read [Panel Preferences Dialog](http://docs.xfce.org/xfce/xfce4-panel/preferences).

Comment: I've done this, but the selected button, or the one who's under the mouse is still in blank, and I would like to make this transparent (or with an opacity of 10%).

Comment: Same here. I'd love to know an answer to this.

Answer (score 2):

O.S. UbuntuStudio 15.10 x386

This works for me. Create a file `~/.gtkrc-2.0` and save with this content:

```
style "xfcepanel"
{
xthickness = 0 # from here until "Modd 10" is not relevant for this forum thread...
ythickness = 0
GtkButton::inner-border = {3,1,1,1}
#XfcePanelWindow::autohide-size = 1
font_name = "Modd 10" # ...but i left it here to show how these things work.
engine "pixmap" {
        image {
            function    = BOX
            recolorable    = TRUE
            state        = NORMAL
            }
        image {
            function    = BOX
            recolorable    = TRUE
            state        = PRELIGHT
            file        = "Panel/panel-button-hover.png"
            border        = { 3, 1, 1, 1 }
            stretch        = TRUE
            }
        image {
            function    = BOX
            recolorable    = TRUE
            state        = ACTIVE
            file        = "Panel/panel-button-active.png"
            border        = { 3, 1, 1, 1 }
            stretch        = TRUE
            }
        image {
            function    = BOX
            recolorable    = TRUE
            state        = SELECTED
            file        = "Panel/panel-button-active.png"
            border        = { 3, 1, 1, 1 }
            stretch        = TRUE
            }
        image {
            function    = BOX
            recolorable    = TRUE
            state        = INSENSITIVE
            }
        image {
            function    = ARROW
            recolorable    = TRUE
            arrow_direction    = DOWN
            }
        }
}
widget_class "XfcePanelWindow*" style "xfcepanel"
```

[image: Snapshot working transparent panel config]

In Panel 1 (that I add) I disable label buttons:

[image: disable buttons in panel 1]

You need drag to left to Alpha 0:

[image: You need to drag to left to Alpha 0 in Appearance Tab of XFCE Panel Config]

From [this Ubuntu Forum thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1973741)

**ERROR MESSAGE**

Only I have one problem, on restart I see a message:

[image: imagen de error]